# I'm creating a "Guess the number" game, and I don't know how to restart a part of code

Tags: java

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Adivinha {

    public static Scanner escolha;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int min = 0;
        int max = 0;
        boolean falso = false;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 100));

        escolha = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tentativa = escolha.nextInt();

        if ((tentativa == randomNum) == falso) {

            if (tentativa > 100 || tentativa < 0) {
                System.out.println("Só números entre 0 e 100");
            }

            if (tentativa > randomNum) {
                System.out.println("A tua Tentativa é Maior que o número que tens que Adivinhar");
                }

            if (tentativa < randomNum) {
                System.out.println("A tua Tentativa é Menor que o número que tens que Adivinhar");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the code.
I want to make it so the player can retype a number to guess the Random number that was generated.

Comment: I think you need two loops: An outer game loop that initializes the number to be guessed, and an inner loop controlling user input for a particular game.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you want something to happen repeatedly until a condition is met, you're talking about a loop.  If the action to repeat is "prompt the user for input" and the condition is "the input is valid" then in your case a single instance of this loop might look something like:

```
int tentativa = -1;
while (tentativa > 100 || tentativa < 0) {
    tentativa = escolha.nextInt();
    if (tentativa > 100 || tentativa < 0) {
        System.out.println("Só números entre 0 e 100");
    }
}
```

You might tweak the messaging to the user to make the interface a little more intuitive, but the overall process is simple.  The structure is basically:

```
Set value to an invalid default
Loop while the value is invalid
    Prompt for a new value
    If the value is still invalid, show a message
```

As long as the user keeps entering an invalid value, the loop will continue.  As soon as a valid value is received, the loop will terminate and the logic of the program can continue.